# How do I write into a file (css)

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, css

I'm writing my first wp plugin and I have many problems, most of those I got to solve by just reading the codex, but I don't know how to write into a css file within my plugin's options. Maybe there's a better way of doing it, but what I had in mind was using  a text field and saving that into an empty custom.css file that would be packed with the plugin. I don't want having to save css info into the wp_options table. Is there a standardized way of having custom css for your plugins which could be changed by the user without having to open the css file themselves??

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7048/best-practices-for-a-style-css-based-theme-options-page

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with saving CSS to the database? That is the correct approach. And that way, you can simply output the options to a function, which can be enqueued properly, using `wp_print_styles`, and entirely avoid file operations/writing to .css files.

Comment: Well I didn't know that Chip. Thanks for your response. How do I save it though? everything in one field like a big string? or should I add several fields in my form labeled as the attrs?

Comment: It depends entirely on what your options are. If, e.g. you're allowing the user to customize colors, then I would have one text field for each element, to hold the user-specified color value. But if you're allowing general "custom CSS", then you might use a textarea instead. (Note that the former is much easier to validate/sanitize than the latter.)

Comment: Yeah, I guess I know what you mean Chip. It would be rather complex if I were to validate a whole text area. I guess that's why I would rather store that somewhere else other than the database

Comment: Well, not really, because it's still just CSS that goes into the textarea. The *sanitization* is easy ( `wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $input['some_textarea_css'] );`, but the *validation* would be more difficult (if you even attempt to validate arbitrary CSS).