# wp_enqueue_style with style.php and Wordpress functions

Tags: php, css, wp-enqueue-style, wp-load.php

I use wp_enqueue_style to add my stylesheet, like this:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.php', false, '1.0', 'all' ); ?>
```

It works fine BUT **I need to run a Wordpress function in the style.php file**. The stylesheet file does not know that the core exists.

**This is what I've heard**

- It's bad to include `wp-load.php`.
- It's bad to include the stylesheet directly to `header.php` because plugins can't find it.
- It's bad to include the stylesheet directly to `wp_head` functions because plugins can't find it.

Is there a "correct" way to do this?

Comment: to run a wordpress function you will need to load wp-load.php which is not a good idea. If you can please explain more why you need to run a wordpress function some here might suggest you better alternative.

Comment: I have a plugin that echos CSS-files in the style.php and at the same time saves them as a cached file.

Depending on if I'm on localhost or not it uses the PHP-file or the cached CSS-file.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the answers of these questions:

1. [How do I add CSS options to my plugin without using inline styles?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/how-do-i-add-css-options-to-my-plugin-without-using-inline-styles)
2. [Best way of adding CSS which can be manipulated by the user via theme option panels?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16714/best-way-of-adding-css-which-can-be-manipulated-by-the-user-via-theme-option-pane)
3. [Best practices for a Style/CSS based theme options page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7048/best-practices-for-a-style-css-based-theme-options-page)